# Instagram API hashtag and content use on public app

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

So I want to use hashtags along with my own data for public sites or businesses, but it seems this is against IG policy.

> This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display).

Seems I can only show my own content unless the person's IG account gives us permission with IG login.  Otherwise we can't show someone's pictures or hashtags on a public site

I did seem something about paying for the IG api? Is it possible to do this?  I couldn't find anyone to contact.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a third-party platform that powers this use case. 
https://smashballoon.com/instagram-feed/demo/

Comment: I think the above is only for your own instagram account, it doesn't allow you to search for someone or place and then display their instagram data. They won't legally allow it i think

Comment: Prevously I have received an comment from Instagram. If you are trying to display hashtag content for a one-off project (e.g. a website for a brand, event or hashtag contest), 
note that we do not support one-off and single use projects. We recommend that you use a third-party platform that powers 
this use case.

Comment: That's for your product, or your brand.  I'd want to combine google maps search with IG tags, but IG isn't going to allow that from what I read.  I could do it easy with their API, but it would be against their TOC

Comment: If you are thinking to combine with Google Map, you need to create a platform yourself. If you show Instagram data not in the public space, Instagram will allow to use public_content.

Comment: The platform is no problem, it's just a question of can I use the data for a public search engine.  Everything I've read says no, I'm just wondering if maybe there's another way.

Comment: There is no way, if you use IG API.